# Prove that homotopy classes influence isomorphism classses.

Tags: general-topology

A bundle is a continuous map $p:Y\to X$ with a selected fiber $F$
so that for each $x\in X$, there is an open neighborhood $N_x$ of $x$ and a homeomorphism
$p^{-1}N_x\cong N_x\times F$ such that
$$(p^{-1}N_x\xrightarrow{\cong} N_x\times F\xrightarrow{\pi_1} N_x)=(p^{-1}N_x\xrightarrow{p}N_x).$$
It follows that $F\cong p^{-1}(x)$.
Now let $p$ be a bundle with fiber $F$, and $f:A\to X$ a continuous map, so we can form
the pullback of topological spaces

$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{llllllllllll}
Z&\ra{}&Y\\
\da{p'}&&\da{p}\\
A&\ra{f}&X
\end{array}.
$$
We know that if $p$ is a bundle with fiber $F$, then $p'$ is a bundle with fiber $F$.

My question this time is if $g$ is homotopic to $f$, how do I prove that it pulls back to a bundle isomorphic to $p'$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true under mild restrictions. See

> Husemoller, Dale. Fibre bundles. Vol. 5. New York: McGraw-Hill, 1966.

In Chapter 4 "General fibre bundles" the concept of a principal $G$-bundle is introduced. Here, $G$ is a topological group. For $G$ = trivial group you get the concept of a bundle as in your question.

In Theorem 9.9 it is shown that for *numerable* principal $G$-bundles you get an affirmative answer to your question. *Numerable* is a technical ingredient. All bundles over paracompact spaces are numerable.